# Is double buffering in java-me phones useful?

Tags: java, java-me

Is it useful?

specifically in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the device. GameCanvas  have a doble buffer, you can acces to this buffer using the getGraphics() methods. The other way is use a simple Canvas and create an image, get the graphics of this image and use as doble buffer.